# how to solve multi-equation with known and unkown variable in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, equation

I have 4 equations , and I know x and y and ans1 to ans4. but I want matlab solve these 4 equations and give me a,b,c,d. what should I do?

```
  ans1 = I(x,y);
  ans2=I(x+1,y); 
  ans3=I(x,y+1);
  ans4=I(x+1,y+1);  

a*x+b*y+c*x*y+d==ans1
a*(x+1)+b*y+c*(x+1)*y+d==ans2
a*x+b(y+1)+c*x*(y+1)+d==ans3
a*(x+1)+b*(y+1)+c*(x+1)*(y+1)+d==ans4
```

Comment: Side remark: Don't use MATLAB for this kind of task but Mathematica, if you have access to it.

Comment: @RobertStettler but this is a image processing matlab code and it's not possible to use another app. what about using string to number converter to tell matlab x is number and it's not passive?

Comment: @patra I don't get the question. When you say you "know" `ans1` to `ans4` does that mean we can treat them as constants? or `I` in this case is some known function of `x` and `y`? not clear. if `ans1`, `ans2`, `ans3`, `ans4`, and `x` and `y` are constants, then this is just solving a simple linear system

Comment: But when I use
 S=solve(a*x+b*y+c*x*y+d==ans1,a*(x+1)+b*y+c*(x+1)*y+d==ans2,a*x+b(y+1)+c*x*(y+1)+d==ans3,a*(x+1)+b*(y+1)+c*(x+1)*(y+1)+d==ans4);
matlab got confused and has error.

Comment: you need to write the system in matrix form as `A*x=b` and use `\` to solve... don't use `solve` in this case.

Comment: @transversalitycondition   yes these are simple linear system. but notations and syntax in matlab is my problem

Comment: that's not my name, but anyway, if you can't put in the effort to figure out basic matrix algebra I can't help you

Comment: @transversalitycondition [a b c d] * inv([x y xy 1]) == [ans1 ans2 ans3 ans4]. that 's it. But I don't know how to use it in matlab

Comment: OP says `x` and `y` are known and constant so... doesn't matter.

Comment: @patra you should just be able to use the `/` or `\\` operator: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/systems-of-linear-equations.html

Comment: @Dan yeah, probably not a duplicate because it's in the documentation :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the question is formulated, I guess the answer is

```
[x y x*y 1; (x+1) y (x+1)*y 1; x (y+1) x*(y+1) 1; (x+1) (y+1) (x+1)*(y+1) 1]*[a b c d]'=[ans1 ans2 ans3 ans4]'
```

Or

```
A = [x      y      x*y          1 
     (x+1)  y      (x+1)*y      1
     x      (y+1)  x*(y+1)      1
     (x+1)  (y+1)  (x+1)*(y+1)  1];

x = [a
     b
     c
     d];

b = [ans1
     ans2
     ans3
     ans4];

A*x == b;
```

hence to solve for `x`:

```
[x y x*y 1; (x+1) y (x+1)*y 1; x (y+1) x*(y+1) 1; (x+1) (y+1) (x+1)*(y+1) 1]\[ans1 ans2 ans3 ans4]'
```

Or

```
A\b;
```